# WCF REST Web Service and HTTP Headers

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest, http-headers

I've created a REST web service that returns a simply id passed in xml format.

However, as part of the xml returned, I want to include custom headers.  I want to be able to read the data in the request headers and return some of them back in the response.

For example, if the request includes Header1 and Header2, I want to return Header1 and Header2 as part of the response, along with a new header, Header3.

I'm struggling to work out where and how to do this so any help would be appreciated.

My code:

RestServiceImpl.svc.cs:

```
namespace RestService
{
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        #region iRestService Members

        public string XMLData(string id)
        {
            return "You requested product " + id;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

IRestServiceImpl.cs:

```
namespace RestService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
        string XMLData(string id);

    }
}
```

Comment: But your service works insofar, that you can return the ID? It's just the headers that are your problem?

Comment: @khlr Yes, the service works fine in terms of the ID. I'm not sure how to read/write the headers. If the request includes CustomHeader1 and CustomHeader2, I want the response to include CustomHeader1, CustomHeader2 and CustomHeader3

Answer (score 12):

You can access requested header using folowing.

```
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext ctx = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current;
String request_header_value1 = ctx.IncomingRequest.Headers["Incoming_Req_Header_Key1"].ToString();
```

Here, `Incoming_Req_Header_Key1` is key of incoming header , like `Incoming_Req_Header_Key1: Incoming_Req_Header_Value1`, so request_header_value1  = `Incoming_Req_Header_Value1`.

In response, you can use above string and append more result such as "CustomHeader3" ( just an example from yours) to response. And if you want to append them to response header, you can do that by using `ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers`.

**UPDATE**

I have used following code.

[image]

Here is the output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Did you mean ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers?  Also, where would I place the code? The following code within XMLData(string id) doesn't work. ...
{            System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext ctx = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current;
            String request_header_value1 = ctx.IncomingRequest.Headers["Incoming_Req_Header_Key1"].ToString();
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Incoming_Req_Header_Key1", request_header_value1);

            return "You requested product " + id;
}

Comment: @kong88 , yes you are right, it is `OutgoingResponse` and it should work, let me have a look.

Comment: @kong88, It is working as expected. In your case, it might be breaking if you are not passing `Incoming_Req_Header_Key1` in wcf request header ( i mean if you are not passing,then it will be null, nothing will not be added to response header).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.  So the GetData method should be a part of the RestServiceImpl class? And I should call it in IRestServiceImpl just like the XMLData?

Comment: When I call getData, what should I pass in as the value parameter?

Comment: @kong88, this is just an example, you should take your example and see , if that works, for my case ( the example with getdata), url template was `UriTemplate = "GetData/{value}"` and url  is `service1.svc/getdate/abc`, here `abc` is parameter